# Get an IP adress of a client of a SOAP service

Tags: python, soap

I'm writing a SOAP service using python and soaplib. I need to get IP adresses of all clients of the service to store them to the log file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to implement a "hook" which is called at different stages of the wsgi executation.  See the section "Hooks" in the [soaplib readme](http://github.com/jkp/soaplib/blob/master/README.markdown) file for details and the example [hook.py](http://github.com/jkp/soaplib/blob/master/examples/hooks.py) in that distribution.

For example, you could implement `onMethodExec` and then use the wsgi `environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')` to obtain the client's IP address and log it.